# HttpClient MultipartFormDataContent Post Request with 500 Error Code

Tags: c#, httpclient

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        var values = new[]
       {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signer[email]", "mrafi127@yahoo.com"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signer[first_name]", "Rafi"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("signer[last_name]", "Qureshi"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("transaction_name", "Miguel's TPS notarization for Leeroy"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("transaction_type", "Power of Attorney"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message_to_signer", "Please notarize your TPS Report"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message_signature", "Love, Leeroy."), 
        };

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
        }

        content.Add(new StreamContent(System.IO.File.Open(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Individual_Formx.pdf"), FileMode.Open)), "document", "Image.pdf");

        var result = client.PostAsync("https://api.notarize.com/v1/transactions", content);
        result.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine(result.Result.ToString());
```

It gives the following result
**Id = 61, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n  Vary: Origin\r\n  X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 3\r\n  X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 10968\r\n  X-Request-Id: 6daf37b5-16b6-47d1-87bb-8e3a3798d4f0\r\n  X-Runtime: 0.379850\r\n  Connection: keep-alive\r\n  Date: Wed, 03 May 2017 01:59:36 GMT\r\n  Server: Cowboy\r\n  Via: kong/0.9.7\r\n  Content-Length: 1477\r\n  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n}"**

Comment: Could you please tell the API Name

Comment: here is documentation:
http://dev.notarize.com/#create-a-transaction

and this api
https://api.notarize.com/v1/transactions